# Form validation is ignoring validation for "name" input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm making a form for a project and the form needs to have validation. The validation is working fine for email and institution, but it seems to ignore the name validation. Can someone please help?

```js
var name = document.forms["download__form"]["name"],
email = document.forms["download__form"]["email"],
institution = document.forms["download__form"]["institution"];

function validation() {
  if(name.value == "") {
    window.alert("Name must be filled!");
    return false;
  }

  if(email.value == "") {
    window.alert("Name must be filled!");
    return false;
  }

  if(email.value.indexOf("@", 0) < 0) {
    window.alert("Name must be filled!");
    return false;
  }

  if(email.value.indexOf(".", 0) < 0) {
    window.alert("Name must be filled!");
    return false;
  }

  if(institution.value == "") {
    window.alert("Name must be filled!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="form__fill" name="download__form" onsubmit="return validation()">
  <input type="text" class="form__input" name="name" placeholder="NAME*" />
  <input type="text" class="form__input" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL*" />
  <input type="text" class="form__input" name="institution" placeholder="INSTITUTION/ORGANIZATION*" />
  <p>*Must be filled</p>
  <input type="submit" name="download" class="form__button" id="form__button" value="Download.PDF" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form class="form__fill" name="download__form" onsubmit="return validation()">
  <input type="text" class="form__input" name="name" placeholder="NAME*" />
  <input type="text" class="form__input" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL*" />
  <input type="text" class="form__input" name="institution" placeholder="INSTITUTION/ORGANIZATION*" />
  <p>*Must be filled</p>
  <input type="submit" name="download" class="form__button" id="form__button" value="Download.PDF" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Javascript
var name = document.forms["download__form"]["name"],
email = document.forms["download__form"]["email"],
institution = document.forms["download__form"]["institution"];

function validation() {
  if(name.value == "") {
    window.alert("Name must be filled!");
    return false;
  }

  if(email.value == "") {
    window.alert("email must be filled!");
    return false;
  }

  if(email.value.indexOf("@", 0) < 0) {
    window.alert("email must be valid");
    return false;
  }

  if(email.value.indexOf(".", 0) < 0) {
    window.alert("email must be valid");
    return false;
  }

  if(institution.value == "") {
    window.alert("institution must be filled!");
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

There is nothing wrong with your code.. The email validation is creating confusion as you have a same alert value for all the alerts the same. Just enter the email address correct and code will work fine.I have changed the values for u too

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. What do you mean by enter the email correct?

Comment: you have a email validation. for which there should be like 'something@anything.com' if you are entering anything else it will show an alert. but if you enter it as specified above there will be no issue. Copy paste the code in you text editor and ull know. PS: I u think i have solved your problem please accept my answer

Comment: can u explain the error? I redid your code and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine. You have put all the alert messages as **Name must be filled**. Therefore if any field gives error it alerts **Name must be filled**. Just change the alert message related to specific fields and it wont give unnecessary error for name field

```js
var name = document.forms["download__form"]["name"],
email = document.forms["download__form"]["email"],
institution = document.forms["download__form"]["institution"];

function validation() {
  if(name.value == "") {
    window.alert("Name must be filled!");
    return false;
  }

  if(email.value == "") {
    window.alert("Email must be filled!");
    return false;
  }

  if(email.value.indexOf("@", 0) < 0) {
    window.alert("Email format is not correct!");
    return false;
  }

  if(email.value.indexOf(".", 0) < 0) {
    window.alert("Email format is not correct!");
    return false;
  }

  if(institution.value == "") {
    window.alert("Institution must be filled!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="form__fill" name="download__form" onsubmit="return validation()">
  <input type="text" class="form__input" name="name" placeholder="NAME*" />
  <input type="text" class="form__input" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL*" />
  <input type="text" class="form__input" name="institution" placeholder="INSTITUTION/ORGANIZATION*" />
  <p>*Must be filled</p>
  <input type="submit" name="download" class="form__button" id="form__button" value="Download.PDF" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your name control doesnot have a value and also not initialized and hence it is returning `undefined` when no value if typed. You need to put the check like

```
if(typeof name.value == "undefined" || name.value =="")
```

and also you need to follow the suggestion people have given here as changing the message for different type of validations.

Hope this helps,